formatting output of gvar
I use the gvar library in python. This example, taken from the documentation gives an error:
>>> import gvar
>>> x =  gvar.gvar(3.14159, 0.0236)
>>> print(f'{x:.2g}', f'{x:.3f}', f'{x:.4e}', f'{x:.^20.2g}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/gvar/_gvarcore.pyx", line 92, in gvar._gvarcore.GVar.__format__
ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'str'
>>> 

The version of gvar I am using is 11.11.12.
How should I fix the code with this version of gvar?

That's a pretty old version.

Looks like the old version doesn't support formatting specifications. Either avoid them, switch to a newer version, or implement formatting yourself. You can see how the new version does it.
